# WPF Large uniformGrid performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, itemscontrol, uniformgrid

I'm trying to display a map using an `ItemControl` and an `UniformGrid`. The map is an observable collection of Cells.
When the map is large the rendering time is very big and I'm struggling to lower it.

Here is the concerned code:

```
   <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Do not use binding because it's slow -->
                    <!-- Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CellClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" -->
                    <!-- CommandParameter="{Binding}" -->
                    <Button Name="Button" Style="{StaticResource CellButtonStyle}" Tag="{Binding}"
                            Click="Cell_OnClick"
                            MouseEnter="Cell_OnMouseEnter"
                            MouseRightButtonUp="Cell_OnMouseRightButtonUp" />

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIncluded}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIncluded}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCurrentPlayerLocation}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Content" Value="X" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCurrentPlayerLocation}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Content" Value="" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 Columns="{Binding Header.ColumnCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Rows="{Binding Header.RowCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I've tried replacing the `Button` with a `Rectangle`, it does improve the situation but it still takes > 10sec to display a 400x300 map.

Any ideas on how to make the rendering fast?

Comment: That's 120000 cells? It will always take a few seconds to render such an amount of UI elements. What kind of "map" is this supposed to be?

Comment: Would it not be better to render the map as an image? What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a map for a game. The user can click on each cell to make it "walkable" or "non walkable". Using an image may be a bit tricky as I need to locate which cell the user clicked

Comment: You might want to use a Canvas and set the coordinates of your elements manually. In any case, the amount of cells you're generating will be slow if all those cells are WPF controls. Are you sure, WPF is the right framework for you? (btw. you could definitely find the clicked cell from an image with some basic math)